# How to install gnome desktop in ubuntu

Tags: gnome, x2go

I am using ubuntu vps (OVH) and have access though ssh .

I want some graphical user interface and found Gnome is good .

I have installed gnome desktop and x2go server but i cannot connect to it through x2go ..

anyone minds sharing some detailed guide ?

Thanks

Comment: I would not do any of that. Use a web interface designed for servers, there are several to choose from, webmin, cockpit, sort of depends on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

GNOME v3 is known to not work with x2go. XFCE / Xubuntu definitely works very well
This could help you: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-x2goserver-on-ubuntu-14.04-as-vnc-alternative

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.